# Converting Hashmap to CSV in Kotlin Android

Tags: kotlin

Hi I am trying to convert a hashmap where hashmap =
private var Sdata:MutableMap<String, MutableList> = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList>()

Sdata currently looks like the picture below:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNLCR.png[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNLCR.png%5Benter) link description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNLCR.png)

My code to convert my hashmap to csv looks like this: @Credit to Михаил Нафталь

```
binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener() {
 
        Sdata = viewModel.savehash
        val csv = File(this.filesDir, "test.csv")
        val valuesSeparator = ","
        val lineTerminator = "\r\n"
        val rowTerminator = "["
        //write header, overwrite file if it has existed
        csv.writeText(
            Sdata.keys.joinToString(
                separator = valuesSeparator,
                postfix = lineTerminator
            )
        )
        //write rows
        val nRows = Sdata.values.maxOf { it.size }   // if size of all lists are not equal
        //val nRows =   Sdata.values.first().size        // if size of all lists are equal
        for (i in 0 until nRows) {
            val row = Sdata.values
                   //.map { it[i] }               // if it's guaranteed that size of all lists is the same
                .map { it.getOrElse(i) { "" } } // otherwise
                .joinToString(separator = valuesSeparator, postfix = lineTerminator)
            csv.appendText(row)

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "CSV VIEW: $Sdata")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved to Documents", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

I was able to get my csv file successfully but the data format is off:
[CSV File](http://%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSb0U.png) [2](http://%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSb0U.png):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSb0U.png
How should I fix This? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you may have new line characters in the values of your map, you might want to try `.trim()`. Also, please **please** don't post screenshots of this stuff, you can post the console output as a code block

Comment: Hi, I am new to kotlin and I am uncertain where I should be trimming the new lines?

Comment: Inside the `map {}`, instead of `it.getOrElse(i) { "" }` you can use `it[i]?.trim() ?: ""`

Comment: @Joffrey Thankyou so much good sir! You are amazing!

Comment: Please keep in mind that you may have edge cases where the content of one cell may contain a comma or a double quote character, and this would break your code.  I suggest using a library to avoid having to deal with such cases, e.g., Apache Commons CSV